# Using an existential theorem in Coq

Tags: coq, theorem-proving

I have the following theorem in Coq: `Theorem T : exists x:A, P x.` I want to be able to use this value in a subsequent proof. I.E. I want to say something like: "let `o` represent a value such that `P o`. I know that `o` exists by theorem `T`..."

How would I do this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Mathematically speaking, you need to apply an elimination rule for the ∃ constructor. The generic elimination tactic `elim` works.

```
elim T; intro o.
```

Silly example:

```
Parameter A : Prop.
Parameter P : A -> Prop.
Axiom T : exists x:A, P x.
Parameter G : Prop.
Axiom U : forall x:A, P x -> G.
Goal G.
Proof.
elim T; intro o.
apply U.
Qed.
```